# AMP-page link to a redirected page

Tags: amp-html

I recently changed the URLs of my articles and they are now 301 redirected to the new URL format. However, the AMP equivalent version of those articles  `rel="canonical"` tag still links to the old version of the URL (now a 301 page).

Is this ok?

Ie, given  `<link rel="canonical" href="$SOME_URL">` , can `$SOME_URL` be a redirected page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this questions belongs to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Apologies emix. I found a reference on the AMP pages itself to stakoverflow and the tag amp-html. Thanks